# Unity EditorWindow - Save popup while changing scenes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

So I am making a kind of Scene Management in my EditorWindow, I was wondering if there is any way of giving the same popup when you try to change the current unsaved scene as you get in the normal way?

[image]

```
if(GUILayout.Button("Main Menu"))
{           
    EditorSceneManager.OpenScene("Assets/_Scenes/00MainMenu.unity");
}

if(GUILayout.Button("Level01"))
{
    EditorSceneManager.OpenScene("Assets/_Scenes/01Level.unity");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all currently opened scenes you can use e.g. [EditorSceneManager.SaveCurrentModifiedScenesIfUserWantsTo](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.SaveCurrentModifiedScenesIfUserWantsTo.html) like

```
if(GUILayout.Button("Main Menu"))
{   
    if(EditorSceneManager.SaveCurrentModifiedScenesIfUserWantsTo())
    {
        // user said yes -> scene was saved
        EditorSceneManager.OpenScene("Assets/_Scenes/00MainMenu.unity");
    }
    else
    {
        // user said no -> evtl. abort or do nothing?
    }
}

if(GUILayout.Button("Level01"))
{
    if(EditorSceneManager.SaveCurrentModifiedScenesIfUserWantsTo())
    {
        // user said yes -> scene was saved
        EditorSceneManager.OpenScene("Assets/_Scenes/01Level.unity");
    }
    else
    {
        // user said no -> evtl. abort or do nothing?
    }
}
```

However note Unity's little hint ^^

> Note: Currently a window with three buttons is shown. Save and /Don't Save/ both cause the Scene(s) to be written. Cancel leaves the Scene(s) untouched.

---

Alternatively you could also use [EditorSceneManager.SaveModifiedScenesIfUserWantsTo](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.SaveModifiedScenesIfUserWantsTo.html) in order to limit the saving to a certain array of scenes.